Attribute error with ELMo embedding for CNN model
Having an issue with implementing ELMo embedding with a CNN model. I originally has some tokenization and padding but removed these steps as I am not sure they are needed when using pre-trained embedding (please correct me if I'm wrong). I'm having an attribute error but not sure what it means at all or how to fix it. I tried adding the x_train['tweet'].astype(str) section but that's led to the same error. I know using standard tensorflow.keras instead of tf_keras is an option however I was obtaining different errors before that where the model summary was blank.
The splitting of the data:
#importing data split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x = seeker_df[['tweet']]
y = seeker_df['BinaryNumTarget']

#splitting into validation and test - 85% of dataset if train and validation, 15% for test
x_train_val, x_test, y_train_val, y_test = train_test_split(x,
                                                            y, 
                                                            test_size =0.15,
                                                            stratify = y, # sampling used to ensure class distribution
                                                            random_state = 42)

#splitting into train and val - 70% for training, 15% for validation
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train_val, 
                                                  y_train_val, 
                                                  test_size =0.1765,
                                                  stratify = y_train_val, 
                                                  random_state=42)
#splitting creates 70% training set, 15% validation set, 15% test set

x_train = x_train['tweet'].astype(str)
x_val = x_val['tweet'].astype(str)
x_test = x_test['tweet'].astype(str)

Packages:
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf
#!pip install tf_keras
import tf_keras as tfk

from tf_keras.src.engine.sequential import Sequential
from tf_keras.src.layers.convolutional.conv1d import Conv1D
from tf_keras.src.layers.pooling.global_max_pooling1d import GlobalMaxPooling1D
from tf_keras.src.layers.core.dense import Dense
from tf_keras.src.layers.reshaping.reshape import Reshape
from tf_keras.src.layers.reshaping.flatten import Flatten

The embedding:
#obtaining elmo emmbedding
elmo = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", 
                      trainable = False, 
                      name = 'elmo_embedding', 
                      input_shape = [],
                      dtype=(tf.string))

#setting up parameters
max_length = 200
no_of_filters = 250
kernel_size = 3
hidden_dims = 250
batch_size = 32
epochs = 2

The model build:
model = tfk.Sequential()
model.add(elmo)
model.add(Reshape((1024, 1)))

model.add(Conv1D(no_of_filters, kernel_size, activation ='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(no_of_filters, kernel_size, activation ='relu'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(hidden_dims, activation = 'relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])


model_history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                        validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                        batch_size= 32, 
                        epochs= 5)

The error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 23
     15 model.compile(optimizer='adam',
     16                   loss='binary_crossentropy',
     17                   metrics=['accuracy'])
     19 model.summary()
---> 23 model_history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
     24                         validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
     25                         batch_size= 32, 
     26                         epochs= 5)


AttributeError: in user code:
File "C:---tf_keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1398, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "C:---\tf_keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1381, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "C:---\tf_keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1370, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "C:---\tf_keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1151, in train_step
    self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
File "C:---\tf_keras\src\optimizers\optimizer.py", line 622, in minimize
    grads_and_vars = self.compute_gradients(loss, var_list, tape)
File "C:---\tf_keras\src\optimizers\optimizer.py", line 280, in compute_gradients
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'outer_context'


I switched the embedding model to NNLM available on TensorFlow Hub, as the
Elmo model from Kaggle was not compatible. The new model is working well, and
after training, I've achieved better accuracy. Please refer to this gist, and
let me know if you're still encountering any issues.
